# Laravel Query String vs Get Parameters?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I"m using Laravel framework and I have situation adding routes based on different conditional parameters.

Currently, I'm using this code.

```php
Route::get('/{report?}/{type?}', [
    'uses' => 'SomeController@getReport'
])->where(['report' => 'overview', 'type' => 'type1']);
```

---

```
www.example.com/overview/type1  // Working
www.example.com?report=overview&type=type1 // Not working (not verifying the where conditions).
```

I have another solution to resolve this. Is this a better way?

```php
if (Input::get('report') == 'overview' && Input::get('type') == 'type1') {
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'SomeController@getReport']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (request()->get('report') == 'overview'
   && request()->get('type') == 'type1') {
   Route::get('/', [
     'uses' => 'SomeController@getReport'
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will work.

```
      Route::get('/{report?}/{type?}', function()
       {
          if (Input::get('report') == 'overview'
                && Input::get('type') == 'type1') {
              // Run controller and method
              $app = app();
              $controller = $app->make('SomeController');
              return $controller->callAction('getReport', $parameters = array());
          }
       });
```